# What's the hybridization in diphosphorus molecule?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, vsepr-theory

I read that diphosphorus has 2 phosphorus atoms joined by a triple bond (ie) it has one sigma bond and 2 pi bonds with 2 lone pairs ( 1 lone pair on each atom). I'm confused about the hybridization of the orbitals. Phosphorus in excited state has one 3s orbital, three 3p orbitals and one d orbital .

If **sp2** hybridization takes place, it will form one sigma bond and what about the other 2 hybridized orbitals what would become of them? I'm confused on the lone pair part :/

If the above even took place, would the unhybridized p orbital form pi bond with the unhybridized p orbital of the other phosphorus. And the same would go for the 2 d orbitals. Am I correct on this??

note :https://socratic.org/questions/does-nitrogen-n2-and-oxygen-o2-goes-through-hybridization-how-can-i-know-when-hy

Here it says that "Diatomic molecules don't need hybridisation that is phosphorus would be using p pi p pi bonding which it could never do cuz of large diffuse orbitals !!

Comment: Note: [diphosphorus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diphosphorus) is unstable. Natural phosphorus will instead exist in alltropes like white, red, or black phosophorus, which have entirely different structures.

Comment: Yes diphosphorus is unstable but I'm curious about it's hybridization . If the phosphorus undergoes sp hybridisation then 2 p orbitals and a d orbital will be left behind .

Comment: You can leave orbitals even $\ce{N2}$ has extra $p$ orbitals.

Comment: @AvatarShiny which orbitals ?

Comment: My bad we don't leave orbitals in N2 but you can leave put orbitals